# How to use *.pub/*.sec files to encrypt/decrypt another file?

Tags: gnupg

I created a pair of `*.pub` and `*.sec` files using the instructions and code given here:

https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html

(I am using this documentation because the ultimate application I have in
mind is an automated encryption/decryption pipeline.)

**Q1:** How can I use gpg2 and the `*.pub` file to encrypt another file?

**Q2:** How can I use gpg2 and the companion `*.sec` to decrypt a file encrypted using the companion `*.pub` file?

---

***Important:***  *I am interested only in answers that are suitable for programmatic implementation of an unsupervised operation. Please do not post answers that can only be carried out interactively.  I am particularly interested in solutions that can be implemented in Python.*

---

Please include precise pointers to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Check gpg documentation.

Comment: @MartinZeitler: So what is the *.pub file for then?

Comment: @kjo with `PGP` this is actually true: https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~adrian/630-f04/PGP-intro.html#p9 ...will leave an answer.

Comment: You don't "use the files" to encrypt/decrypt anything, you use the keys that are contained in them; however, you have to import the keys into your PGP/GPG keyring in order to use them. After that, the files have no more use.

Comment: that's why my answer merely focused on "important" automation aspect; while editing it I've also wrote that they theoretically could be deleted. however, the public keys still would have use for sharing them, that's why I've removed that again. publishing them to a key-server is probably the best use for them.

Comment: Can you confirm you want to programmatically use gpg2, and not gpg v1?

Comment: @Bsquare: Actually, I am somewhat confused on this question.  I have read conflicting information (e.g. `gpg2` is supposedly "better", for some value of "better", but it is also supposedly optimized for interactive operation, which is not what I'm working on).  At the moment my choice of `gpg2` is dictated primarily by the fact that it's what is currently installed on the system I am using.  If, however, `gpg` is better for what I want to do, I open to the idea of using it; I would just have to request to have it installed.  As you can probably tell, I am very confused.

Comment: Yes, it is quite confusing. I posted a complete answer to your question; Let me know if your need further information ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some information about what you said:

> I created a pair of *.pub and *.sec files using the instructions

Perfect to share the public key(s) with people you are exchanging information, but technically, when you are working programmatically, you don't need to use these files directly.

To be noted:

- when you encrypt data, you will specify the recipient corresponding to the key to use to encrypt
- when you decrypt data, you will first import the owner's public key, and then you will be able to decrypt data without specifying recipient, because it is embedded in the encrypted data

> Actually, I am somewhat confused on this question. I have read conflicting information [...]

I agree it's quite confusing. In this situation, I think it is better to use version 1 for which there is more experience, and for which you find third party library to use.

In this answer, I tried:

- **[python-gnupg](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/)** (for GnuPG v1) which is a well known Python library and match perfectly your needs
- **[cryptorito](https://github.com/Autodesk/cryptorito)** (for GnuPG v2) for which I didn't find enough documentation

With the first library, you can simply install it in your system:

```
sudo pip install python-gnupg
```

And then write a Python script to perform all the operations you want.

I wrote a simple one to answer your question.

```
#!/bin/python

import gnupg

GPG_DIR='/home/bsquare/.gnupg'
FILE_TO_ENCRYPT='/tmp/myFileToEncrypt'
ENCRYPTED_FILE='/tmp/encryptedFile'
DECRYPTED_FILE='/tmp/decryptedFile'
SENDER_USER='Bsquare'
TARGET_USER='Kjo'

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=GPG_DIR)

print("Listing keys ...")
print(gpg.list_keys())

# On SENDER_USER side ... encrypt the file for TARGET_USER, with his public key (would match the kjo.pub if the key was exported).
print("Encrypting file " + FILE_TO_ENCRYPT + " for " + TARGET_USER + " ...")
with open(FILE_TO_ENCRYPT, "rb") as sourceFile:
    encrypted_ascii_data = gpg.encrypt_file(sourceFile, TARGET_USER)
    # print(encrypted_ascii_data)
    with open(ENCRYPTED_FILE, "w+") as targetFile:
        print("encrypted_ascii_data", targetFile)


# On TARGET_USER side ... decrypt the file with his private key (would match the kjo.sec if the key was exported).
print("Decrypting file " + ENCRYPTED_FILE + " for " + TARGET_USER + " ...")
with open(ENCRYPTED_FILE, "rb") as sourceFile:
    decrypted_ascii_data = gpg.decrypt_file(sourceFile)
    # print(decrypted_ascii_data)
    with open(DECRYPTED_FILE, "w+") as targetFile:
        print(decrypted_ascii_data, targetFile)
```

To be noted my keyring contains pub/sec pair for my `Bsquare` user, and the pub key of `Kjo` user.

Answer (score 1):

when looking at [encrypting and decrypting documents](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html#AEN111)

this hints for [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/); while I can provide regular `expect` scripts:

this is not directly a Python solution, but it should be easy to port.

as the tagline reads:

> Pexpect makes Python a better tool for controlling other applications.

**Encryption**:

```
gpg --output doc.gpg --encrypt --recipient blake@cyb.org doc
```

as `expect` script; usage `./encrypt.exp doc blake@cyb.org 1234` (notice the space after the `:`):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set filename [lindex $argv 0]
set recipient [lindex $argv 1]
set passphrase [lindex $argv 2]

spawn gpg --output $filename.gpg --encrypt --recipient $recipient $filename
expect -exact "Enter pass phrase: "
send -- "$passphrase\r"
expect eof
```

**Decryption**:

```
gpg --output doc --decrypt doc.gpg
```

as `expect` script; usage: `./decrypt.exp doc 1234`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set filename [lindex $argv 0]
set passphrase [lindex $argv 1]

spawn gpg --output $filename --decrypt $filename.gpg
expect -exact "Enter pass phrase: "
send -- "$passphrase\r"
expect eof
```

**Import:**

keys can be imported into either key-chain with:

```
gpg --import somekey.sec
gpg --list-secret-keys

gpg --import somekey.pub
gpg --list-keys
```

there barely is anything to automate; however setting an imported key as "trusted" would require `expect` for automation. found this [cheat-sheet](http://irtfweb.ifa.hawaii.edu/~lockhart/gpg/), which has all commands on one page; and it also hints for: `If you have multiple secret keys, it'll choose the correct one, or output an error if the correct one doesn't exist` (which should confirm my comment below).

file `~/.gnupg/options` is a user's [options file](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/r1172.html#OPTIONSFILE); where one can eg. define the default key-server.

Comment: It is completely bewildering to me that it is so difficult to get an answer to my question, even after offering the biggest bounty I can.  Even though my question emphasizes, over and over, that I want to use a pub file for encryption, your answer doesn't even bother to mention them.  What more must I do to make myself understood?

Comment: @kjo read the documentation; you have to add the keys into a key-ring or a key-server; then these keys are available to `gpg` infrastructure; of course I did not bother to mention them, simply because they cannot be directly passed to the command and therefore play no role for the automation - that's why it is assumed, that key material is available. and with unattended key-generation, the script which does that, also has to add them. in general, the `recipient` parameter dictates which key to use - and either it is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

[Since version 2.1.14](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html), GPG supports the `--recipient-file` option, which lets you specify the public key to encrypt with without using the keyring. [To quote the developer](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-devel/2016-July/031308.html):

> It is now possible to bypass the keyring and take the public key
>   directly from a file.  That file may be a binary or an ascii armored
>   key and only the first keyblock from that file is used.  A key
>   specified with this option is always fully trusted.
>
> This option may be mixed with the standard -r options.
>   --hidden-recipient-file (or -F) is also available.
>
> To futher assist some use cases the option
>
> --no-keyring
>
> has also been implemented.  This is similar to
>
> --no-default-keyring --keyring /dev/null
>
> but portable to Windows and also ignores any keyring specified
>   (command line or config file).

So to encrypt, you would do:

```
gpg --output myfileenc --encrypt --recipient-file key.pub myfile
```

To automate, in addition to using `expect` or Python as explained in the other answers, you can also [use the `--batch` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase). (You will need to see which of the offered answers works best on your system).

No such option, however, is available for the secret key, and, as a matter of fact, the same version of PGP (2.1) [deprecated the `secring` option](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html) in the `--generate-key` command, so this file is not even available any more. The generated key will need to be added to the keyring to be used for decryption.